# $\operatorname{Span}(A \cup B)= \operatorname{Span}(A)+\operatorname{Span}(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let there be $A,B\subseteq V$ subspaces of $V$

1. $\operatorname{Span}(A \cup B) = \alpha_1a_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n a_n + a_{n+1} b_1 + \cdots + \alpha_k b_k=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_ia_i+\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^k \alpha_ib_i$$
   $$ = \operatorname{Span}(A)+\operatorname{Span}(B)$

2.

$A\subseteq \operatorname{Span}(A \cup B)$ and $A\subseteq \operatorname{Span}(A \cup B)$ because a span of a a set contains the set itself.

$\operatorname{Span}(A)\subseteq \operatorname{Span}(A \cup B)$ and $\operatorname{Span}(B)\subseteq \operatorname{Span}(A \cup B)$ because a span of a set bigger than the set itself contains that set of the span on the set itself.

$$\operatorname{Span}(A)+\operatorname{Span}(B)\subseteq \operatorname{Span}(A \cup B)$$

How to Prove $\operatorname{Span}(A)+\operatorname{Span}(B)\supseteq \operatorname{Span}(A \cup B)$?
Does Proof 1 is ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can understand the idea of your proof which's correct but the way of writing is wrong. Notice that $\operatorname{span}(A)$ is a subspace so in particular it's a set and then your writing:

> $$Span(A \cup B)=\alpha_1a_1+...+\alpha_na_n+\alpha_{n+1}b_1+...+\alpha_kb_k=...$$

doesn't make sense. To rectify you may write:

Let $x\in \operatorname{span}(A\cup B)$ then $x$ takes the form
$$x=\alpha_1a_1+...+\alpha_na_n+\beta_{1}b_1+...+\beta_kb_k\\=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_ia_i+\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \beta_ib_i \color{red}{\in} \operatorname{span}(A)+\operatorname{span}(B)\cdots$$

Comment: So if I prove that a general element x from $A \cup B$ is in Span(A)+Span(B) and because it is equalities so the proof is right?

Comment: Yes by double inclusion you prove the equality.

Answer (score 0):

No, the proof has a flaw if you have assumed that a1 to an are bases of A and a(n+1) to a(k) are bases of B because it is very well possible that they have some common bases, and so you need to eliminate the dependent vectors and re-state the statement with the remaining bases as a combination of bases of A and B.